# run.as option does not work other than Nifi user

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to run my NiFi application using ec2-user rather than default nifi user. I changed run.as=ec2-user in bootstrap.conf but it did not worked .It is not allowing me to start Nifi application getting following error while staring nifi service.

```
./nifi.sh start
nifi.sh: JAVA_HOME not set; results may vary

Java home:
NiFi home: /opt/nifi/current

Bootstrap Config File: /opt/nifi/current/conf/bootstrap.conf

User Runnug Nifi Application : sudo -u ec2-user
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi
```

Any pointer to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a file permission problem, which is not covered by installing the service with `nifi.sh install`.  A summary of the required permissions includes:

- Read access to the entire distribution in the NIFI_HOME directory
- Write access to the NIFI_HOME directory itself - NiFi will create a number of directories and files at runtime including logs, work, state, and various repositories.
- Write access to the `bin` directory
- Write access to the `conf` directory
- Write access to the `lib` directory, and to all of the files in the `lib` directory

It is certainly possible to narrow the permissions by creating the working directories manually, and by adjusting NiFi's settings to rearrange the directory layout.  But the permissions above should get you started.

Comment: so what is the solution? I ran into the same problem even with nifi-1.8.0 version. Running nifi.sh install throws how to overcome this > "Current user does not have write permissions to /etc/init.d. Cannot install NiFi as a service."

Comment: I'm successfully able to run run-nifi.bat file. If there is no write access to bin,,lib dirconfectories how can run-nifi.bat file works?

Comment: The solution for running NiFi is that the account that runs NiFi must have the read and write permissions described above (NiFi 1.8.0 may be slightly different).  Running `nifi.sh install` does not grant these permissions.

Comment: The solution for installing NiFi is to run `nifi.sh install` with an account that has permissions to modify /etc/init.d.  This is typically an admin user, or accomplished with `sudo nifi.sh install`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I downloaded `nifi-1.23.0-source-release.zip` rather than `nifi-1.23.0-bin.zip`. After that, I followed this guide https://unixcop.com/how-to-install-apache-nifi-ubuntu/, and nifi run correctly on my aws instance.