# Can't start NiFi in win10

Tags: java, installation, apache-nifi, cloudera

I have installed NiFi but when I try to start it from the command line, with `bin\run-nifi.bat`, I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.RunNiFi
```

I have:
Windows 10 SO 19042.867
Java 8 1.8.0_291-b10

I tried doing it from administrator but it still doesn't work.... can anyone help me?

Thankyou!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can not run Apache nifi on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38604052/can-not-run-apache-nifi-on-windows)

Comment: Run `cmd` as *Administrator* may help.

Comment: both solutions didn't work for me :(

Comment: Did you get it from here - https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?path=/nifi/1.13.2/nifi-1.13.2-bin.zip

Comment: Have a look at this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607634/run-as-option-does-not-work-other-than-nifi-user

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED the exact same problem by granting permissions (full control) to Users and Authenticated Users; I assume only one of these groups was necessary but shotgunned it, and it now runs correctly

[image]